# why sometimes windows can't find my VM

Tags: windows, networking, dns

This is a very weird problem -- I **am** able to find my VM *normally*, but there are times when I can't find my VM in my company network, which is Windows based.

Below is what the symptoms. I.e., `ping` was unable to find my VM, while `nslookup` shows it just fine, even if I'm not specifying the FQDN. Again,

- my company network is Windows based,
- my VM is Linux based, and

  - I am able to `dig` & `ping` my VM, if and only if I'm using the FQDN, while
  - normally the short name works fine as well.

Symptoms from Windows side:

```
D:\>ping myvm.mycompany.com
Ping request could not find host myvm.mycompany.com. Please check the name and try
again.

D:\>nslookup myvm
Server:  dns1.mycompany.com
Address:  192.168.25.200

Name:    myvm.mycompany.com
Address:  192.168.18.244


D:\>ping myvm.mycompany.com
Ping request could not find host myvm.mycompany.com. Please check the name and try
again.

D:\>nslookup myvm
Server:  dns1.mycompany.com
Address:  192.168.25.200

Name:    myvm.mycompany.com
Address:  192.168.18.244
```

Comment: You can always modify the hosts file if the ip address is static.  This sounds something only the IT staff the manages the domain servers can answer.

Comment: No, that's purely Windows networking issue. As I said, there has been times when I can't find my VM, but that's only once out of a blue moon. Having restarted my VM, I can find my VM now, in the same DOS session, without IT staff doing anything. That's why I think it's purely Windows networking issue.

Comment: Like I said you can modify the `hosts` file and create a static connection to the server address provided its not subject to change. You can also make sure when your unable to ping said address your using the correct DNS servers. During these periods of downtime were the dns servers ( dns1.mycompany.com ) also down?  You were able to do a nslookup because Windows keeps a cache.

Comment: The dns servers ( dns1.mycompany.com ) is not down, as I am able to `dig` & `ping` my VM in my VM using it.